# Deja Dup overwritten files

Tags: data-recovery, deja-dup

I have restored by deja dup an old version of our database so it has overwritten the current updated file.
is there anyway I can get the overwritten file back?

Comment: Only if you have a current backup ..

Comment: so no hope what so ever?

Comment: try this https://superuser.com/questions/446277/how-to-recover-a-file-overwritten-with-another-in-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)